# How to fix my leaking bathroom sink?

Tags: plumbing, leak, sink

My bathroom sink has a slow persistent leak, and I cant get at the plumbing to fix it, because the pedestal/wall and putty are in the way.

Is this a take the sink out and start again job, or is there an easier solution?

[image: Bathroom sink, with water leak]

It leaks from where two copper pipes are joined by a fixture, to make it worse, the fixture has some [milliput](http://www.milliput.com/) in an attempt to stop the leak, which is hard to remove.

[image: leaking join in pipes]

The sink doesn't appear to be attached to the wall.

[image: Sink fixture]

Answer (score 1):

If you are certain that the leak is indeed coming from one of those compression style unions and you do not have enough room to attempt to tighten them in place, yes you will have to remove the sink.

Check closely at the base of the pedestal before pulling it away from the wall, there are usually bolt holes at the bottom for fastening the pedestal to the floor.

Comment: +1. Remove the sink and sweat some valves where those couplings are. Subject to vibration, compression fittings *will* leak. Also, you don't use tape on comp. fittings....

Answer (score 0):

IF you can cut the pipe below the leak you MAY be able to solder an extension piece onto it. Looks really tight in there, one of [these](http://www.globalindustrial.com/p/plumbing/plumbing-tools/pipe-tube-cutters/model-no-103-close-quarters-tubing-cutter-18-58-capacity?infoParam.campaignId=T9F&gclid=CjwKEAjw07nJBRDG_tvshefHhWQSJABRcE-ZzfVVjFJCLdxwug9mgkc4e7o39Lx08yLHKydfhszl6BoCOanw_wcB) may work for cutting it.